# How to Wirte OR/and Query in magento2.?

Tags: magento2, collection, query

### SELECT `main_table`.`sku`, `main_table`.`order_id`, `main_table`.`parent_item_id`, `main_table`.`name`, `main_table`.`product_id` FROM `sales_order_item` AS `main_table`
WHERE (`order_id` = '3')
AND (`parent_item_id` IS NULL)
AND
(
(`sku` LIKE 'WSH06%') OR (`sku` LIKE 'MS10%') OR (`sku` LIKE 'MT08%')
)

```
$sku = ['WSH06','MS10','MT08'];
$this->itemF ->create()->getCollection()
                       ->addAttributeToSelect('sku')
                       ->addAttributeToSelect('order_id')
                       ->addAttributeToSelect('parent_item_id')
                       ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
                       ->addAttributeToSelect('product_id')
                       ->addAttributeToFilter('order_id', array('eq' => $order_id))
                      ->addAttributeToFilter('parent_item_id', array('null' => true));
foreach ($sku as $key => $value) {
    $collectionData->addFieldToFilter('sku',array('like' => $value.'%'));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to make or condition in the collection you need to follow the below steps.

```
$sku = ['WSH06','MS10','MT08'];
$this->itemF ->create()->getCollection()
                       ->addAttributeToSelect('sku')
                       ->addAttributeToSelect('order_id')
                       ->addAttributeToSelect('parent_item_id')
                       ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
                       ->addAttributeToSelect('product_id')
                       ->addAttributeToFilter('order_id', array('eq' => $order_id))
                      ->addAttributeToFilter('parent_item_id', array('null' => true));

$likeField = [];
$likeValue = []
foreach ($sku as $key => $value) {
    $likeField[] = 'sku';
    $likeValue[] = array('like' => $value.'%');
}

$collectionData->addFieldToFilter($likeField, $likeValue);
echo $collectionData->getSelect()->__toString();
```

> you need to pass array argument in addFieldToFilter to apply or condition.

hope this will work for you!

Thanks & Regards,
Nirav Patel

Comment: Thank You for your quick supports